# Fluid Dynamics: Understanding check. 2d Eulerian Velocity and Lagrangian Velocity.

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I've just started learning Fluids and have been given an assignment of which i want to make sure i'm right before i hand it in. If it's possible, can you fine ladies and gents of math stack exchange please have a tertiary glance over it and if you see any glaring errors, perhaps make me aware of it. specifically, if there's any gaps in knoweledge i would appreciate the help immensely

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

> Consider The 2D Eulerian Velocity Field given by $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r},t) = \left(\frac{2x}{1+t},0\right)$
>
> - Find the Position, $\mathbf{r}(t;\mathbf{a})$ of a particle released in the flow from $\mathbf{a} = (a,0)$ at $t=0$ (ie. the particle path)

now from my understanding $\mathbf{r}(t;\mathbf{a})$ is just saying the function r (location vector) with initial conditions a,

My solution:
We know that pathlines are given by the following equation.
$$\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt} = \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r},t)~\implies$$
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \frac{dx}{dt} &= u(x,y,z,t) &= \frac{2x}{1+t} \\ 
 \frac{dy}{dt} &= v(x,y,z,t) &= 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$$\implies$$
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 x(t) &= \int u(x,y,z,t) dt &= 2x \ln (1+t) + c_1 \\ 
 y(t) &= \int v(x,y,z,t) dt &= c_2
\end{matrix}\right.$$

plugging in ititial conditions gives

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 x(0) &= 2x \ln (1) + c_1 = a\\ 
 y(0) &= c_2 = 0
\end{matrix}\right. \implies$$
$$\mathbf{r}(t) = \left(\begin{matrix}
 x(t) \\ 
 y(t)
\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
 2x \ln (1+t) + a \\
  0
\end{matrix}\right)$$

> - Find the Lagrangian Velocity, $\mathbf{v}(t;a),$ of the particle and it's (Lagrangian) acceleration

We know that the Lagrangian Velocity is $v(t) = \frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt}$

This seems somewhat odd to me given that we used $\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt}$ to find r in the first place, in which case would we not simply just use the definition of  u to quote v? this seems somewhat confusing to me, i'm sure the question is well defined but i'm finding it difficult to quite understand what i'm being asked here

in anycase. $$\mathbf{v}(t) = \left(\frac{2x}{1+t},0\right)$$

Because Lagrangian Velocity and formulation of Fluid flow has us moving within the flow i imagine that the definition of Lagrangian Acceleration is just 
$$\frac{d \mathbf{v}}{dt} = \left(\frac{-2x}{(1+t)^2},0\right)$$

> - Confirm that the relationship $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}(t;a),t) = \mathbf{v}(t;a)$ between the eulerian and lagrangian velocities hold

I'm interpreting this as making sure that u and v are equal to each other and they remain equal at the initial conditions. in which case

$$\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}(t;\mathbf{a}),t) = \mathbf{v}(t;a) = \left(\frac{2x}{1+t},0\right)$$

and

$$\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}(0;\mathbf{a}),0) = \mathbf{v}(0;a) = \left(\frac{2a}{1},0\right)$$

and so the properties hold.

> - Compute the quantity

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t} + (\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\nabla})\mathbf{u} $$

> evaluated at the point $\mathbf{r}(t;\mathbf{a})$ and confirm it matches the lagrangian acceleration

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -\frac{2x}{(1+t)^2}$$
$$(\mathbf{u \cdot \nabla})\mathbf{u} = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{2x}{1+t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}0\right)\left(\frac{2x}{1+t},0\right) = \frac{4x}{(1+t)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t} + (\mathbf{u \cdot \nabla})\mathbf{u} = \frac{2x}{(1+t)^2}$$

where have i gone wrong? (for instance i can see that my version of the Lagrangian acceleration doesn't match up to the Lagrangian Derivative...)

cheers for any help given, very much appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, could the point of the final question possibly be that the two don’t coincide? I understand that $\partial v  / \partial t$ Is an oversimplification in terms of a time derivative, but I could really use some feedback as I’m currently looking to find a mistake that (may or may not) be there

Comment: In the first part when you had $x'(t)=2x/(1+t)$, this cannot just be integrated directly, you have to solve the (separable) ODE.